# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se lea un número decimal o binario en java y que lo convierta a su opuesto?

Tags: java

Tengo ya planteado cómo convertir de decimal a binario y de binario a decimal pero no sé cómo hacer que elija un camino u otro.
No sé si se deba hacer por métodos y todavía soy algo nuevo en esto.
El código que llevo hasta ahora es este:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Conversordecimalbinario {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingrese un numero binario o decimal: ");

    long numero = scanner.nextLong();
    long temporal = numero;
    String binario = "";

    //conversion decimal a binario
    while (temporal > 0) {
      binario = temporal % 2 + binario;
      temporal /= 2;
    }
    System.out.println("El numero a binario es " + binario);

    //conversion binario a decimal
    long numerobinario = Long.parseLong(binario);
    long numerodecimal = 0;
    int contador = 1;
    long temporaldos;
    while (numerobinario > 0) {
      temporaldos = numerobinario % 2;
      numerodecimal = numerodecimal + temporaldos * contador;
      numerobinario /= 10;
      contador = contador * 2;
    }
    System.out.print("El numero " + binario + " en decimal es " + numerodecimal);
    scanner.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Y cómo vas a saber si un número es decimal o binario si el usuario no lo indica?? Asumimos que si solo tiene 0 y 1 es binario? Y qué pasa si yo quiero convertir a binario el número 110 decimal? No se puede hacer un conversor que *adivine* el formato cuando el formato es ambiguo. El único que sabe lo que quiere convertir es el usuario, y debería poder indicarlo.

Comment: Hola @david, los métodos son fundamentales en programación. Yo crearía dos métodos: conversorDecimalBinario y conversorBinarioDecimal; y ya desde el mismo método principal o desde otro método (p.e. conversorPrincipal), preguntar al usuario qué desea hacer (como ha dicho el compañero) e invocar una u otra función. A ver qué te dice el resto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la retroalimentación contemplando el caso y tratando de eliminar la ambigüedad use switch para preguntarle al usuario que desea hacer y realizar el ciclo según el caso aunque aun hay un caso que no se como resolver y es cuando se ingresa un numero decimal para convertir de binario a decimal gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo los consejos el código hasta ahora ha resultado así.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Conversordecimalbinario {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         
         //preguntar al usuario que tipo de conversion hacer
         System.out.println("Elija una opcion: ");
         System.out.println("1.Convertir decimal a binario");
         System.out.println("2.Convertir binario a decimal");
         
        int opcion= scanner.nextInt();
        
        //convertir el numero segun la opcion del usuario
        switch(opcion) {
        case 1:
            
            //convertir decimal a binario
            System.out.println("Has elegido convertir decimal a binario.");
            System.out.println("Ingrese el numero decimal");
            
            long numero=scanner.nextLong();
             long temporal=numero;
             String binariouno="";
             
             while (temporal>0) {
                 binariouno=temporal%2+binariouno;
                 temporal/=2;
             }
             //escribir el numero binario
             System.out.println("El numero a binario es "+binariouno);
            break;
            
        case 2:
            
            //convertir binario a decimal
            System.out.println("Has elegido convertir binario a decimal.");
            System.out.println("Ingrese el numero binario");
            
            long binario=scanner.nextLong();
            long numerobinario=binario;
             long numerodecimal=0;
             int contador=1;
             long temporaldos;
             
             while(numerobinario>0) {
            temporaldos=numerobinario%2;
            numerodecimal=numerodecimal+temporaldos*contador;
            numerobinario/=10;
            contador=contador*2;
             }
             
             //escribir el numero decimal
             System.out.print("El numero a decimal es "+numerodecimal);
            break;
            
        default:
            //mostrat opcion no disponible
            System.out.println("Opcion no valida.");
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: En una palabra, perfecto!.

Comment: Bienvenido. Esto no es un foro y esto no parece responder a tu pregunta. Si la respuesta te sirvió, dale un voto positivo. Si te permitió solucionar el problema marcarla ✅. Si te quedó alguna duda puedes editar la pregunta. O si los cambios son muchos, mejor crea una nueva pregunta. Por cierto las preguntas basadas en opiniones son cerradas. Así que revisa [ask] antes.

Answer (score 0):

lamentablemente, en algunos escenarios, es imposible saber si una entrada es un número binario o decimal, un ejemplo es el decimal "1000" que tiene en su contraparte binario el número ocho que se escribe "1000", entonces, te propongo un código donde se le pregunta al usuario, que tipo de conversión quiere realizar y luego se le pide el número a convertir:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
System.out.println( "Si desea hacer un conversión de decimal a binario " +
                    "presione 1,\n si desea hacer un conversión de " +
                    "binario a decimal, presione 2 " ); 
int tipoConversion = scanner.nextInt();

if( tipoConversion == 1 ) {
   System.out.println( "Ingrese un numero decimal " );
   long numero = scanner.nextLong();
   long temporal = numero;
   String binario = "";

   //conversion binario a binario
   while( temporal > 0 ) {
      binario = temporal % 2 + binario;
      temporal /= 2;
   }
   System.out.println( "El numero decimal " + numero + " expresado en binario es " + binario );
}
else {
   //conversion binario a decimal
   System.out.println( "Ingrese un numero binario " );
   long numero = scanner.nextLong();
   long numerodecimal = 0;
   int contador = 1;
   long temporaldos;
   long binario = numero;
   while( numero > 0 ) {
      temporaldos = numero % 2;
      numerodecimal = numerodecimal + temporaldos * contador;
      numero /= 10;
      contador = contador * 2;
   }
   System.out.print( "El numero binario " + binario + " expresado en decimal es " + numerodecimal );
}
scanner.close();
```

Como verás, usé tu código, con muy poca modificación.

Comment: Muchas gracias segui los consejos y los demas comentarios y añadi esa opcion de preguntarle al usuario que desea hacer.